# Record checkbox values on change

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a function that requires me to record the value of a checkbox as the key to an associative array whenever the checkbox is changed. This part was not difficult. I also have a "Check All" button. This is the issue. I am uncertain of how to get the check all button to perform the same as individual units.

```
var allchecked = false;
var checkstatus = [];

$(".check-all-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (allchecked == false) {
        $("input:checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
        $(".check-all-button").html("Uncheck All");
        allchecked = true;
        // Update checkstatus array here to [val] = true for all checkboxes
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
        $(".check-all-button").html("Check All");
        allchecked = false;
        // Update checkstatus array here to [val] = false for all checkboxes
    }
});

$("input:checkbox").change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        checkstatus[this.value] = true;
    } else {
        checkstatus[this.value] = false;
    }
});
```

There is also the possiblity that there are other "hidden checkboxes" (or hidden inputs holding a value) that will be part of the array, so I cannot simply change every value to true or false, just those tied to `input[type=checkbox]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to iterate through and set the values:

```
//checking ALL the boxes
$("input:checkbox").each(function(e) {
    checkstatus[this.value] = true;
});

//unchecking
$("input:checkbox").each(function(e) {
    checkstatus[this.value] = false;
});
```

Comment: Aha, the `.each()` function is exactly what I was looking for! Wonderful.